# Creating a simple submenu drop down using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation

Here's an [example](http://jsbin.com/welcome/4812/edit) of what I'm aiming for:

---

I don't like I have to decorate a `li` element with a class in order to correctly fire the event. What happens if I have more than one nested category drop down? Things get messy quick!

I also can't seem to be able to select an option without it closing as soon as I leave the event capture area.

Any suggestions on how to build a well crafted, drop down navigation menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need any classes with some clever usage of the selectors :P

I set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XKuUa/) with an example, here's the code:

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">OFFERS</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">NEW</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>YAY!</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">SETTINGS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TV's</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">COMPUTERS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">RICE</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>​
```

As you see, not a single class/id was needed :P The element "OFFERS" is the only one with a drop-down menu, and inside that menu, the element "NEW" has another one.

CSS:

```
li > ul { display: none; }
li li { margin-left: 10px; }
```

The first style is the important one. At first, we want our submenus to be hidden. The other style is just for the sake of clarity.

jQuery:

```
$("nav ul li").hover(function(){
    if ($("> ul", this).length > 0) {
        $("> ul", this).show();
    }
}, function(){
    if ($("> ul", this).length > 0) {
        $("> ul", this).hide();
    }
});​
```

Yup, as simple as that :) When we `hover` a menu element, we check if it has any `ul` direct children, if it does, we show them. When we leave the menu element, we check again if it has any `ul` direct children, and if it does, we hide them.

Of course, you'll need to style this up, and make sure your clear any float inside any `li`.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use classes to properly control the flow. Especially on your outer container.

For example in my menus i have a `ul` containing all the menu and each menu item is an `li`. Inside the `li` is the first level title, along with another `ul` containing the submenu.

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
        Item 1
        <ul><!--Further items--></ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        Item 2
        <ul><!--Further items--></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can then control this using child selectors. Although it is sometimes easier to simply use a class.

```
$(".menu > li") //First level items
$(".menu > li > ul") //Submenus
```

Say you wanted to make the menu slide down when you clicked on one of the first level items:

```
$(".menu > li").click(function() {
    $this = $(this); //Caching. Not really needed for this example. But anyway :)
    $this.children("ul").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function(){ 
   $("ul.MenuNavi li").mouseover(function(){ 
     $(this).children('ul').slideDown('3000'); 
   }); 
   $("ul.MenuNavi li").mouseleave(function(){                    
     $(this).children('ul').stop(true).slideUp('3000'); 
   }); 
});
```

Comment: you need to add the ".stop(true)" to the first part too, in this case the menu wont close